# foreign key daterange filtering in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

for a hotel booking system using django admin, I'd like to filter the rooms available for a given date range, models are as follow

```
class Room(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Booking(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Start date"))
    end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("End date"))
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

how can I filter the rooms in the admin so I can pick a date range and return only the rooms that have no bookings on the select range?

thanks a lot

Comment: posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I tried filtering only using Django, for example like this:

```
response.context_data['cl'].result_list = (
                            Room.objects.filter(~Q(booking__end_date__range=val) &
                                                ~Q(booking__start_date__range=val)))
```

But the results are not entirely correct, so I tried another way.

To pass the range data, I created a form in the admin. To do this, I overridden the `admin/change_list.html template`. The `change_list.html` template is add in the directory: `templates/admin`. In the [changelist_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) method, the context is overridden and the filtered rows are displayed.

I think need to create a date range from each Booking record and compare it to the range that is created from the form dates.
[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is well suited for this purpose.
The following methods are used: [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range), [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

admin.py

```
import pandas as pd
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import TestForm
from .models import *

class Room_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'hotel')
    change_list_template = 'admin/change_list.html'

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        response = super().changelist_view(
            request,
            extra_context=extra_context,
        )

        if request.method != 'POST':
            response.context_data['form'] = TestForm()
        else:
            form = TestForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                response.context_data['form'] = form
                # Getting the start and end from the form
                val = [form.cleaned_data.get('start'), form.cleaned_data.get('end')]

                bkg = Booking.objects.values('start_date', 'end_date', 'room')
                # Create a list based on form dates from and to
                custom_range = pd.date_range(start=val[0], end=val[1])

                df = pd.DataFrame(bkg)

                def f(x):
                    abc = pd.date_range(
                        start=df.loc[x, 'start_date'], end=df.loc[x, 'end_date']
                    ).isin(custom_range)

                    return ~abc.any()

                # List of rooms based on the secondary Booking model whose
                # dates do not intersect with custom_range dates
                room = [df.loc[i, 'room'] for i in range(len(df)) if f(i)]

                # room numbers that are not booked at all
                no_booking = [i.id for i in Room.objects.all() if len(i.booking_set.all()) < 1]
                room = room + no_booking
                response.context_data['cl'].result_list = Room.objects.filter(id__in=room)


                return super(Room_Admin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=response.context_data)

        return response


admin.site.register(Room, Room_Admin)
```

forms.py

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2022, 2025)))
    end = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2022, 2025)))
```

templates

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}

{% block result_list %}
<form action='' method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='adding'/>
</form>

{{block.super}}

{% endblock %}
```