# Creating Custom Filter in Django Admin with JavaScript Flatpickr

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I am currently working on a project where I have successfully integrated Flatpickr calendar into my Django admin view. The calendar allows users to select a date, and I want to extend this functionality by creating a custom filter.

Essentially, I want to replicate the behavior of a Django-filter, but with my custom calendar.

Could anyone provide guidance on how I can achieve this? Are there any existing examples or resources that demonstrate the integration of a custom JavaScript calendar with Django admin filters?

I already tried with [Custom filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) but I can not achieve the functionality that iam looking for

Thank you

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421560/foreign-key-daterange-filtering-in-django-admin/77427064#77427064) I tried to filter the page with model records in the admin panel using the created form with dates. The **changelist_view** method is overridden, in which I change the context.

Comment: I ending using javascript to obtain the dates selected and make a search with that terms. It is not the most correct way, but it works.

Comment: I managed to insert a form from Flatpickr on the admin panel page (model records page) and read the date from it. I did all this in a Django template, since there is a library for it, django-flatpickr. I can show an example in the answer, need a clear definition of what to filter and how?